# What does bash +x <script.sh> option mean?

Tags: bash, shell

I know what is bash -x, but what is bash +x ? Googling found no results and the manual also says nothing about it.

Answer (score 3):

All of the single-character options are as if they were typed in the `set` command.  `-x` turns on option `x`, `+x` turns off option `x`.

Comment: I believe it's turned off by default.

Comment: Yes, but if it is called in a shell where the option is on, they want to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409366/what-is-bash-x

-x turns on x trace and +x turns it off as far as I understand